# Copy certain columns and paste vertically in loop

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to write a VBA script that will do the following.

I would like to Copy B3:B7 and C3:C7 and paste in G2:H6 then I want to grab the date in C2 and paste down in I3:I7. Then I want to repeat that until it hits a blank column, keeping B3:B7 and taking D3:D7 and pasting that underneath in G7:H11 and grab the date in D2 and copying it down in I7:I11.

I've attached pics with data and desired result. Thanks!

[image: Data]

[image: Desired Result]

Comment: Exactly why I posted here.. because I'm stuck. Isn't that what this site is for? I guess I will be more clear next time with where I'm at.

Comment: You’ve struck lucky this time please read [ask] and next time post your own efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some VBA code that finds the last row/column used in your original data, and then loops this to produce the output that you are after.

```
Sub sFixData()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lngLastCol As Long
    Dim lngLastRow As Long
    Dim lngLoop1 As Long
    Dim lngLoop2 As Long
    Dim lngRow As Long
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet3")
    lngLastCol = ws.Cells(2, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    lngLastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    lngRow = 3
    For lngLoop1 = 3 To lngLastCol
        For lngLoop2 = 3 To lngLastRow
            ws.Cells(lngRow, 7) = ws.Cells(lngLoop2, 2)
            ws.Cells(lngRow, 8) = ws.Cells(lngLoop2, lngLoop1)
            ws.Cells(lngRow, 9) = ws.Cells(2, lngLoop1)
            lngRow = lngRow + 1
        Next lngLoop2
    Next lngLoop1
End Sub
```

Regards,

Comment: Spot on my friend. Thank you so much! You just saved me hours.